# Strange extra \else in pgfplots slope field plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to plot a slope field of the function `2x/y` using pgfplots such that the length of each quiver is fixed. The code is below

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            declare function={
                f(\x,\y) = (\y != 0) * (2*\x/\y);
                length(\x,\y) = sqrt(1+(2*\x/\y)^2);
                result = (6 +0.5)/14;
            },
            domain=-0.5:6, 
            view={0}{90},
            axis lines=center
            ]
            \addplot3[blue, quiver={u={1/length(x,y)}, v={f(x,y)/length(x,y)}, scale arrows=result}, -stealth, samples=14] {0};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}% Extra \else. ...e arrows=result}, -stealth, samples=14] {0};
    
\end{document}
```

Here I define my functions and try to use them in the quiver plot. However, I get the following unhelpful error

```
! Extra \else.
\pgfmath@local@next ...@local@function@body \else
                                                  \if #1(\let \pgfmath@local...

l.32 ...e arrows=length}, -stealth, samples=14] {0};
```

I can't see what's wrong with the code. I have tried, without success

- Changing the `/=` sign into other possible alternatives, such as `!=`,
- Plugging in the function calls with their literals

Can I please have some help with this?

Comment: You're missing a `;` at the end of the `result` definition. Aside from that, what is `/=` supposed to represent? The "not equal" comparison operator is `!=`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. that solved those errors, however, there's a new error now saying `Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 'result' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near 'result'.. ...e arrows=result}, -stealth, samples=14] {0};`

Comment: Please post a *complete* compilable example that also shows the packages and libraries you are using.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I did not use any package other than pgfplots and tikz. So I don't think it's necessary to put those in too. None of the things I used in my example seem to come from other packages either

Comment: @Kookie My point is, that with a complete example it is far easier to help you, because we can easily copy and paste the full code and compile it. Also, it is clear than, that you did not use any other packages, and I wouldn't need to ask =)

Comment: @JasperHabicht Understood, I'll edit the code in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your original code you had forgotten a `;` at the end of the definition of `result`. That you get a `Could not parse input 'result' as a floating point number, ...` error indicates that the argument given to `scale arrows` isn't parsed as a number, so the function is interpreted. I don't whether this is a bug or by design. One possible workaround is to use `\pgfmathsetmacro` to parse `result` and save to a macro, as in the example below.

```
\documentclass{article} % don't use minimal https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads tikz

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            declare function={
                f(\x,\y) = (\y != 0) * (2*\x/\y);
                length(\x,\y) = sqrt(1+(2*\x/\y)^2);
                result = (6 +0.5)/14;
            },
            domain=-0.5:6, 
            view={0}{90},
            axis lines=center
            ]
            % make an intermediate macro for "result"
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpres}{result}

            % and use \tmpres for "scale arrows"
            \addplot3[blue, quiver={u={1/length(x,y)}, v={f(x,y)/length(x,y)}, scale arrows=\tmpres}, -stealth, samples=14] {0};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]